# How to check ! $ & present in password variable in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing shell script which will validate entered password which should not accept ! $ & sign in password. I need to throw error messages. Kindly help me here.

Here problem occurring when I give password like yt!$&

It is not throwing me error messages

```
echo "enter password which do not include ! $ & sign" 
read -s password 
if [[ $password != *"&"* || $password != *"!"* || $password != *"$"* ]];
 then 
echo "Do not enter ! $ & in password" else 
echo $password  
fi
```

Comment: something like `echo $INPUT | grep -q "[\$\!\&]" && echo "invalid character found"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x!=a || x!=b || x!=c` is equivalent to `!(x==a && x==b && x==c)`.

This is only true when none of the three conditions match.

However, I guess you wish to fail if even a single condition matches.

For that you should use: `!(x==a || x==b || x==c)`.
Or equivalently: `x!=a && x!=b && x!=c`

After that, it should be clear that you also need to invert the test.

---

You can combine the tests and shorten to:

```
if [[ $password == *[\&!$]*  ]]; then 
    echo "Do not enter ! $ & in password"
else 
    echo $password  
fi
```

(`&` has to be escaped.)

Comment: I see by trial and error, that `&`  indeed needs to be escaped here, but why is this the case? AFIK the only special role of `&` is as a statement separator (when running the preceding command in the backgroun), i.e. `A & B`. But here we are in the context of comparision, and a statement separator can't occur anyway.

Comment: @user1934428 I think any metacharacters need to be escaped (`|&;()<>` and space,tab,newline) because they are parsed out before glob expansion happens. See [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting)

Comment: @user1934428 imagine if the line were `ls /usr/bin/*[&echo ok`

Comment: The example with the `ls` does not count, since in this case, we don't have the specific context introduced by a `[[` expression, in which other parsing rules apply as in normal statements (for instance, word splitting works differently). But I think you are right in that the parser (or, more likely, the lexer) is doing its job first, before the statment parser kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fix your condition:

```
if [[ $password == *"&"* || $password == *"!"* || $password == *"$"* ]]; then
  echo "Do not enter ! $ & in password"
fi
```